# MVC4 UserProfiles has no results after logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

On the new MVC4 it uses SimpleMembership which when logging in contains the line:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
```

After this I did the following to get the extended properties I applied to the UserProfile:

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var user = context.UserProfiles.First(n => n.UserName == model.UserName);
```

But UserProfiles has no results and has a count of 0 from context??? There must be something in there as I'm logging in with a user?

Comment: What do you see if you put a breakpoint on the `var user=` line and examine model.username? Is the correct username provided? Incidentally, `UserProfiles` refers to the table, `user` should be the individual user, so if `UserProfiles` is empty, it implies the table is. Finally, a `First()` should throw an exception if there are no records - does it? Technically `Single()` would be more appropriate here as retrieving 2 users with the same username should also be considered an exception (or `SingleOrDefault()` if you're expecting 0 or 1 results)

Comment: Yes it has 'test@test.com' as model.username.  The table contains data and after all it just logged the user in so must have.  Yes it produces the error 'Sequence contains no elements', changed to Single for better coding.

Comment: Try doing a `foreach (var U in context.UserProfiles){var A = U;}` with a breackpoint on `A=U;` - does it get hit at all? If so, what does `U` look like in the debugger? If not, there's a more fundamental issue in that the user records aren't being read correctly at all. In that case, ignore all the login stuff and try inserting a record using EF. Can you then see _that_ record? If there are problems with the model, the insert will likely fail. Another thing to check... Firs up the SQL Profiler, monitor the SQL commands being generated for the `SELECT` - why isn't it finding the record?

Comment: Found the issue, the connectionkey specified in the base was wrong (don't know why), hence found no records.  Wierd thing is how was it then registering and validating ok for login??

Comment: Because the login isn't handled by EF, it's handled by the `MembershipProvider`, `RoleProvider` and (possibly) `ProfileProvider` - and unless you've written one yourself that implements EF, it'll be using its own mechanism to check the database

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/) for details on implementing your own membership provider. It's pretty noddy to implement (Login, SetPassword, Claim Account stuff, Check Roles, etc...) you then substitute yours for the standard one.