# Invalid Column Name with EF

Tags: entity-framework

I modified the table UserProfile in the database with some extra columns and then modified the UserProfile class to reflect them:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously they are FirstName, Surname and School.  For some reason though despite the register action saving details into all 3 of these new columns when I try to load the data via:

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var user = context.UserProfiles.First(n => n.UserName == model.UserName);
```

It says that School is an invalid ColumnName.  I checked it was a string in both class and table so bit confused how to debug, help!

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but depending on the version of EF you're using, EF stores metadata about the version of the entities/context used when generating the database inside (system) tables in that database. Thus, your manual changes would need to be reflected there too. The preferred method to make these changes is using [migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)

Comment: Is it not possible to simply change the database and class, I'm sure I created EF CF with an existing database without needing migrations whenever I made a change

Comment: it might work but you're making assumptions about the way EF works internally and the implementation isn't guaranteed to change. Eg the naming convention it uses for foreign keys. You can guess these and probably force EF to use your model by applying the appropriate attributes - but as I said, it's not ideal. In your position, I'd use the SQL profiler and see what queries EF is running against the Db - have a look for the column name it's attempting to retrieve (or the metadata tables its checking)

Comment: I have given Migrations a go, after all I'd like to do it properly.  Only problem is in Up() it creates the table again and in Down() it drops the table.  That's fair enough at the start but if I was making changes at a later stage I wouldn't want it to drop tables.  Also it says Table already exists which means it's not dropping first, have I missed something?

Comment: Looked at older project, it works in this case because in the OnModelCreating I am putting:
`modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().ToTable("tblSites");`

Comment: TBH, without seeing your model and migrations, it's very difficult to give an answer. Can I suggest that for testing purposes you point at a brand new db and create V1 of the model, then attempt to `Up()` to V2 and see what happens - it's possible the changes you've made by hand are interfering (that pesky metadata again). Failing that, can you post a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: I simply moved the drop to the Up() and it worked, didn't seem to delete data either.  Got a seperate problem now but this parts fixed, can you put Migrations etc as answer so I can tick.

Comment: Raised second problem in new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586289/mvc4-userprofiles-has-no-results-after-logging-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Continued from comments on OP)

Rather than doing this manually, you should consider using the EF migrations framework - There are a number of benefits and it's more future-proof in case internal EF functionality changes.

See [here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621) on migrations